# How to set the column of the DataGridView by passing another column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to pass calendar column to already exist column of the datagridview or how to set calendar column to already exist column?

I overcast the datagridview column as Calendar column by using this code [Cast Datagridcolumn as calendar type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Everything works fine but I want to pass this column to already exist column in data grid view. This is working fine when I use this logic:

```
metroGrid1.Columns.Add(col);
col.HeaderText = "Mfg. Date";
col.Name = "mfg_+date";
```

But not working when I use this code:

```
CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
metroGrid1.Columns["mfg_date"].DefaultCellStyle. = col;
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: I guest that you want to show DateTimePicker to choose date when you edit cell ?

Comment: @VietDD No I want to replace the existing grid cell with calendar cell. Can you help me out?

Comment: in the link you mentioned : "The following code example shows how to create a calendar column. The cells of this column display dates in ordinary text box cells, but when the user edits a cell, a DateTimePicker control appears."
-> I found an example for that, check my comment bellow

Comment: I want to assign calendar column to already exist textbox column. how to do that

Answer (score 0):

According to mentioned link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> The following code example shows how to create a calendar column. The
>   cells of this column display dates in ordinary text box cells, but
>   when the user edits a cell, a DateTimePicker control appears.

[image: Add DateTimePicker in Datagridview in C#]

Found this example (I dont know which post another site's link here is ok or not, so I copy it, or you can search for '**Add DateTimePicker in Datagridview in C#**') :

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();  
Rectangle _Rectangle;  

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);    
    dtp.Visible = false;  
    dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;   
    dtp.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dtp_TextChange);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        case "Column2":

            _Rectangle = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true); //  
            dtp.Size = new Size(_Rectangle.Width, _Rectangle.Height); //  
            dtp.Location = new Point(_Rectangle.X, _Rectangle.Y); //  
            dtp.Visible = true;

            break;
    }
}

private void dtp_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text.ToString();
}

private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    dtp.Visible = false;
}

private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    dtp.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: this code not responding when the grid size change or form move away

Comment: please explain more about "grid size change or form move away"